# Create a file which cannot be deleted by file.delete()

Tags: java, file, junit4

Note: I am aware there are several questions similar to this one, however, I cannot find any which explain how to resolve the situation I am trying to resolve. I will ask this question with a specific example, for which I need a solution.

Consider the code:

```
private final void writeToFile(final File parent, final String filename, final Charset charset, final String content) throws IOException {
    final File file = new File(parent, filename);

    if (file.exists()) {
        LOG.warn("File {} already exists, file will be replaced.", file.getCanonicalPath());
        if (!file.delete()) {
            logAndThrow(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()), null);
        }
    }

    try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, charset)) {
        writer.write(content);
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test to provoke the IOException being thrown when the code cannnot delete the file. The unit test I have tried is as follows:

```
@Test public void testFileNotDeletable() throws IOException {
  final File file = new File(folder.getRoot(), formattedFile.getMetaData().getFormattedCaptureFileName());
  file.createNewFile();
  try {
    file.setReadOnly();

    exception.expect(IOException.class);
    exception.expectMessage(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()));

    writer.write(formattedFile);
  } finally {
    file.setWritable(true);
  }
}
```

I have also tried locking the file:

```
@Test public void testFileNotDeletable() throws IOException {
    final File file = new File(folder.getRoot(), formattedFile.getMetaData().getFormattedCaptureFileName());
    file.createNewFile();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        final FileLock lock = fis.getChannel().tryLock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
        try {
            exception.expect(IOException.class);
            exception.expectMessage(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()));

            writer.write(formattedFile);
        } finally {
            lock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, the file.delete() successfully deletes the file, and the test fails, as the expected IOException was not thrown.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Note: Added for clarification, some extra code that shows that the File object is completely separate in the environments. The formattedFile being passed to the write method is not a File or sub-class of File, it is one of our internal classes. The File in the JUnit test is using a TemporaryFolder for the root, the formattedFile has a MetaData item, which determines the filename. In my JUnit test I am trying to create an empty file, which cannot be deleted, in the location that my actual code will attempt to write the file. I need file.delete() to return false, so that I can test the exception is being thrown. I therefore cannot mock a File object.

Comment: Mock the call to `file.delete()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old file api instead of the modern NIO revolving around `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`?

Comment: use file permissions that don't allow deletion.

Comment: I did look at the Files interface, however I do not want to use a mechanism that throws an IOException, I want to use one that already encapsulates the logic, and simply returns true/false if it succeeds. Files.deleteIfExists() does not give me what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to your question, I recommend the first one.

- **Solution 1**
  You are not testing the java file I/O operations/class here, you are testing your code's functional behaviour in response to file operation. So, ideally in your JUnit you should be mocking the `File` object & its respective calls, and only focus on testing your code.
- **Solution 2**
  If you still wish to test full integration with java file IO, open file in write mode before attempting to delete, and it will take care of your test case.

*NOTE:* Code tested in CENTOS, WINDOWS, UBUNTU, MAC OS-X

**Subject Class:**

```
    public class FileSolution {
        public void fileHandler(File file) throws IOException, Exception {
            if (file.exists()) {
                LOG.warn("File {} already exists, file will be replaced.", 
                        file.getCanonicalPath());
                if (!file.delete()) {
                    logAndThrow(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", 
                            file.getCanonicalPath()),
                            new IOException(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", 
                                    file.getCanonicalPath())));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Subject Uner Test:**

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class FileSolutionTest {

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    /**
     * Solution 1
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testFileNotDeletableWithMock() throws Exception {
        final File file = mock(File.class);
        file.createNewFile();
        // mock file & IO operations
        given(file.exists()).willReturn(true);
        given(file.delete()).willReturn(false);
        given(file.getCanonicalPath()).willReturn("test.txt");

        exception.expect(IOException.class);
        exception.expectMessage(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()));

        new FileSolution().fileHandler(file);
    }

    /**
     * Solution 2
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testFileNotDeletable() throws Exception {
        File file = null;
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try{
            file = new File("test.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            file.deleteOnExit();
            exception.expect(IOException.class);
            exception.expectMessage(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()));
            // open file with another process for writing
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            new FileSolution().fileHandler(file);
        } finally{
            if(fileWriter != null){
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are OSs that allow deletion even if the file is open in another process.

Comment: Linux is one of them. Opening and locking the file in the test, does not prevent Linux from deleting it.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thus removed OS specific comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent a file from being deleted you have to deny the security permission in windows. From the UI we would need to do something like

1. **Right-click the file or document in your PC => Choose Properties;**
2. **In Security, tab Edit to change permission => Select Add and enter Everyone;**
3. **Press OK and select the group to change Full control permission to Deny;**
4. **Press Yes to confirm.**

The only way I know of to change file permissions with Java are:

```
file.setExecutable(true|false);
file.setReadable(true|false);
file.setWritable(true|false);
```

and

```
File file = new File("test.txt");

if(file.exists())
{
    //Setting file permissions for owner, group and others using PosixFilePermission

    HashSet<PosixFilePermission> set = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();

    //Adding owner's file permissions

    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);

    //Adding group's file permissions

    set.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);

    //Adding other's file permissions

    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    set.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get("test.txt"), set);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Sorry...File doesn't exist.");
}
```

So, preventing a file from being deleted I would assume would have to do with file writing permissions. Try disabling the writable and maybe the executable permissions before trying to delete the file.

If this doesn't work then I do not believe it can be done with the Java language yet as these are the only methods available at the moment for changing file permissions. I could be wrong, but I have been unable to find anything else.

**UPDATE**

For Linux try the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

        String command = "sudo chattr +i /backups/passwd";
        // OR try

        //String command = "sudo chattr +i -V /backups/passwd";

        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }
}
```

The above makes /backups/passwd file immutable (or undeletable). This implies that the file can’t be modified in any way: it can’t be deleted or renamed. You can’t even create a link to it and no data can be written to the file as well.
That's about the only thing I can think of.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is this right-click in PC stuff. I am a developing using Linux.

Comment: Setting the file permissons to 000 yielded no solution. files.delete() still deletes the file.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Turing85 about using mockito.

Let's imagine you have an original class with a method similar to the one you want to test:

```
public class FileDel {

    public void logOnIOException(File file) throws IOException {
        if (file.exists()) {
            LOG.warn("File {} already exists, file will be replaced.", file.getCanonicalPath());
            if (!file.delete()) {
                logAndThrow(String.format("Cannot delete file '%s'.", file.getCanonicalPath()), null);
            }
        }
    }

    public void logAndThrow(String msg, String s) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    private static class LOG {
        public static void warn(String msg, String path) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can trigger an inner exception in this way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FileDelTest {
    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testFileNotDeletable() throws IOException {
        File file = mock(File.class);
        when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
        when(file.delete()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock iom) throws Throwable {
                throw new IOException();
            }
        });

        FileDel f = new FileDel();

        try {
            f.methodToTest(file);
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot mock the File object, it is completely separate from the unit test. I need to mark the actual file so that it cannot be deleted, but file.delete() always succeeds (it appears).

Comment: Hi Marcus. This matter is getting more interesting. Do you want to create a real life test for your app on different OS with existing files really locked? Or rather you would like to mock this behaviour (the file deletion raising an IOException) but you are currently not succeeding in this direction?

Answer (score 0):

What about open `InputStream` for this file and do not close it. Until file's descriptor will not be closed, file will not be deleted.

Comment: Linux allows for the deletion of an open file.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can, with the chattr command set a file that is "immutable" that cannot be deleted even by root.  Someone else said "set file permissions" which is right, but did not give specific detail.

Cheers
D